# What character value does Control + Enter/Return key send?

Tags: .net, vb.net, special-characters, keypress

We have a multi-line control that we are attempting to prevent the Enter/Return key from being used to create a new line.

Strangely enough, "AcceptsReturn" as False does not prevent this.

So we added the following:

```
Private Sub txtAddr_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtAddr.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This works fine, however one of the QA people discovered hitting Control + Enter still puts in a newline.

How would we prevent this?

And why does AcceptsReturn being False not work as it appears it should? What is the intended purpose of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl + enter is most likely to produce a line feed ([ASCII 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)).

It may depend on the specific system though.

If you are checking for carriage return (ASCII 13) and line feed though you probably have most bases covered.

Answer (score 2):

The AcceptsReturn property does something else.  The Enter key normally operates the OK button on a dialog.  With AcceptsReturn = true, the Enter key will enter a new line in the text box instead of activating the OK button Click event.

Pressing Ctrl+Enter will generate a line feed, TextBox treats this as a new line as well.  Use this KeyDown event to filter all combinations:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  if ((e.KeyData & Keys.KeyCode) == Keys.Enter) e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you'd have to trap this in the KeyDown, rather than the KeyPress event.